# How to make Facebook link share thumbnails larger?

Tags: facebook

Ok, so my question is about Facebook link share thumbnail image display. I have tried sharing video links on my Facebook page with lots of different strategies:

I tried uploading image, tried direct link share but nothing seems to do the required job.

I am looking to get this desired result (photo attached) but what I get is a small thumbnail displayed (another image attached) on my Facebook page once the link has been shared. 
[image: This is the result I want]
[image: This is the result I get]

Am I missing something? How do I make my larger image clickable and displayed as it is.
Thanks

Answer (score 5):

Facebook has a [content sharing best practices guide](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/best-practices).  It says:

> `og:image` – This is an image associated with your media. We suggest that you use an image of at least 1200x630 pixels.

If you make your image as big as they suggest it shows up as the larger size.  Smaller images show up as thumbnails.

[Here is an article](http://www.h3xed.com/web-and-internet/how-to-use-og-image-meta-tag-facebook-reddit) that suggests using 1200x1200 square images so that the end up looking good on both Facebook and Reddit.

Facebook's [open graph debugger](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug) tool can be used to see how your page will look on Facebook.    It will give advice about a small `og:image`:

> **Small og:image**: All the images referenced by og:image should be at least 200px in both dimensions, with 1500x1500 preferred. (Maximum image size is 5MB.) Please check all the images with tag og:image in the given url and ensure that it meets the recommended specification.
>
> **og:image should be larger**: Provided og:image is not big enough. Please use an image that's at least 200x200 and preferably 1500x1500. (Maximum image size is 5MB.) Image ... will be used instead.